# How to implement an optional relation?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table A and B, both look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE A (id integer CONSTRAINT aid PRIMARY KEY);
```

Now i want to model an optional one-to-many relation between A and B. Normally, I would extend the definition of B like so:

```
CREATE TABLE B (
    id integer CONSTRAINT bid PRIMARY KEY, 
    a_id integer REFERENCES A(id)
);
```

but now `a_id` can't be `null`, so the relation isn't optional. So basically I want to be able to assign `null` to this column, but if the value is not null then it must reference `A.id`.

Comment: Have you tried putting a `NULL` value into the `a_id` column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `a_id` can be null in table `B`. I tried it:

```
tmp=# CREATE TABLE A (id integer CONSTRAINT aid PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE
tmp=# CREATE TABLE B (
tmp(#     id integer CONSTRAINT bid PRIMARY KEY, 
tmp(#     a_id integer REFERENCES A(id)
tmp(# );
CREATE TABLE
tmp=# insert into B (id,a_id) VALUES (3,null);
INSERT 0 1
tmp=#
```

Your current data model works.

Comment: Oops, indeed it does! I must have mistaken columns or something when I got the error. How embarrasing.

Comment: really, if you want to do it right, you make a third table

Comment: @johannes_lalala would you like to provide a reference?

Comment: @johannes_lalala I'm familiar with database normalization. Nothing on that reference says anything about using 3 tables to express an optional relationship. The word "optional" doesn't even appear on the page.

Comment: See 1.NF. A table with NULL entries does not resemble a mathematical relation which would be required by the common definition for a table being in 1.NF.
To be fair, nullable FKs violating 1.NF is debated. In university I learned that it does, but many argue for a laxer interpretation.
What isn't debated is that you should avoid NULLs wherever possible. They cause unexpected behaviour and get in your way when it comes to portability and especially redesign. From my experience, while they have their use, they regularly cause WTF-moments that consume more time than it takes to make a 3. table.

Comment: Yes, NULLs can cause problems, but in practice sometimes that are good model for a messy world, or can help improve performance by reducing joins. The rise of the NoSQL movement has been in part about addressing practical concerns and in response we see things like PostgreSQL adding JSON support, where you can drop schema-less data (including NULLs!).  See also [Rise and Fall of Third Normal Form](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2012/11/21/rise-and-fall-of-the-third-normal-form/)

Comment: I din't say never use nulls. But in this particular case they can and should be avoided. We don't model an optional value or information that could be undefined at some time. We have to relate sets A and B. So we define the set A and the set B and a relation between them. That is clear, flexible, safe. The performance cost of more joins is almost always negligible and memory usage is reduced most of the time. It can be done consistently. Beside very special cases there is no reason not to do it whereas there are many situations where the quick solution is worse and/or needs to be restructured